# Are all optimization problems convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Recently, a professor at my university made the claim that all optimization problems are convex (after a suitable transformation, if necessary). He is renowned for many important contributions to convex optimization, so I assume that his claim is correct. I would like to understand why this is true and if one can always explicitly construct such a transformation.
A particular example that convinced me to believe that the claim is true is moments-based optimization (cf. [this 
paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1052623400366802) which you find online via google). The idea is that finite-dimensional polynomial (non-convex) optimization problems are equivalent to infinite-dimensional (convex) optimization problems over measures.

I would like to know to what extend this idea can be generalized. Is this possible for general (non-convex) finite-dimensional nonlinear programs? If so, will the convex counterpart always be infinite-dimensional? And can we also transform non-convex infinite-dimensional optimization problems to convex ones?

PS: I am aware of the fact that the above-mentioned claim would not mean that non-convex optimization problems were suddenly easier to solve. I am interested in this for purely theoretical reasons.

Edit: As said above, Lasserre's paper uses the fact that non-convex polynomial optimization problems are equivalent to convex optimization problems over measures. The (short) proof of this fact, however, makes no use of the polynomial nature of the objective function. I believe this can be proven for any (measurable/continuous?) objective function. This would mean that any finite-dimensional non-convex optimization problem is equivalent to a convex optimization problem over measures. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Did he maybe say that all convex optimization problems are conic? If not, you should ask him to support his claim.

Comment: No, the claim was definitely as above. Moreover, as the case of polynomial optimization shows, it seems to be true at least to some extent. I am asking whether the claim is true in full generality (i.e., for non-polynomial or even infinite-dimensional problems) and, if so, why.

Comment: There is certainly no way this is correct in any practical sense. And no, this doesn't make non-convex problems "easier to solve". Nothing in the Laserre paper refutes the intractability of non-convex optimization.

Comment: Consider: what the Laserre paper is saying is that a non-convex problem can be solved to a given non-zero accuracy by solving a finite number of convex problems; and that sometimes you'll get lucky and get the exact solution. That description applies just as well to various branching methods for mixed-integer LP, for instance. It's quite clever that this provides a very general approach, but it's not revolutionary.

Comment: This reminds me of the (true) notion that semidefinite programs can be expressed as semi-infinite linear programs: http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/sip.pdf
(Lasserre looked at this too, in fact)

Comment: As I said above, I am not interested in practical applications of the above statement. Concerning my question, the key point in Lasserre's paper is that non-convex polynomial optimization problems are equivalent to convex (infinite-dimensional) optimization problems over measures, which is shown at the very beginning. The part where Lasserre truncates the moment sequences to arrive at (sometimes exact) finite-dimensional convex relaxations is irrelevant for the above question.

Comment: The relationship between SDPs and semi-infinite linear programs seems interesting, but I think it's not general enough to answer (parts of) my question

Comment: I'd be curious to hear what your professor meant by this comment. Can you just ask them to explain it and report back to us? Ideally with a link to some reference that explains what point the professor was making.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: The claim seems reasonable to me as well. To spell it out, any optimization problem $\min_x f(x) \text{ s.t. } x\in\Omega$ ought be equivalent to a convex (in fact, linear) minimization $\min_\mu \int f\,\mathrm d\mu$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure over $\Omega$. The minimum is attained when $\mu$ is a discrete measure concentrated on the global minimum(s) of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that your optimization problem is

$(P1) \quad \min_{x} f(x)$ such that $x \in \Omega \qquad$,

where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous real-valued function and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set. The assumptions of continuity of $f$ and compactness of $\Omega$ are made to guarantee that a minimum exists ([see Weiertrass' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces)).

This generic optimization problem attains the same optimal value of the convex optimization problem

$(P2) \quad \min_{x,\alpha} \alpha$ such that $(x,\alpha) \in \textrm{conv}(\{x\in \Omega, f(x) \le \alpha\})$,

where $\textrm{conv}(S)$ is the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the set S.

*Remark 1*: As pointed out in the comments, although (P2) has the same optimal value of (P1), it may be the case that the optimal points are different.

*Remark 2*: some authors define differently what is a convex optimization problem, precisely,

$\min_x f(x)$ 
such that 
$ g_i(x) \le 0, i=1,\ldots,m$ and $h_j(x) = 0, j=1,\ldots,k$,
where $f, g_i$ are convex functions and $h_j$ are affine functions.

For more details, see Amir Ali Ahmadi's lecture notes on convex and conic optimization, in particular, pages 13 and 14 of [lecture 4](http://www.princeton.edu/~amirali/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec4_aaa.pdf) from 2016.

Comment: I am very skeptical of the claim of equivalence here. It is far too convenient that _any_ finite-dimensional non-convex optimization problem can be translated to a convex optimization problem simply by applying the standard epigraph transformation? No, I don't buy it.

Comment: Consider a simple example: $f(x)=\sin x$, $\Omega=[-\pi,pi]$. Clearly, the solution to the original problem is $x^*=-\pi/2$, $f(x^*)=-1$. But while the converted problem has the same optimal _value_ of $-1$, it achieves that value on _any_ $x\in\Omega$, because the convex hull reduces to $[-\pi,\pi]\times [-1,+\infty)$. This definitely is not equivalent; for the problems to be equivalent, they would have to obtain the same optimal points.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I believe you have a good point, but in your example, isn't the convex hull given by [this region](https://imgur.com/a/rgCyN)? If this is the case, I think the optimal points (at least in this example) are the same.

Comment: No, I’m afraid it’s simply not the same.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I suppose I am not seeing something obvious, but how do you express $(\pi,-1)$ as a convex combination of points in the epigraph of $\sin x$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: Try drawing out the convex hull @TheoreticalEconomist and make sure that you recognize that the bottom of the convex hull is flat at $3\pi/2$ which forces it to be so across the interval.

Comment: But I might be wrong about that—if so we just change the interval to $[-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ or even multiple cycles of the sine.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Yes, I think your comment is false if we are minimising $\sin x$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$. However, the point you are making is true when $\Omega = [-\pi /2 , 3\pi / 2]$.

Comment: So what is the convex hull of the epigraph when $\Omega = [-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist you're right—the convex hull I cited above is wrong. It follows $\sin(x)$ for $-\pi\leq x\leq-\pi/2$, then it is flat for $-\pi/2\leq x\leq \pi$. So the epigraph model achieves its optimal value for any value of $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi]$. It remains a valid counterexample, just not quite the way I explained it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I don’t think that’s right. The bottom edge of the convex hull of the epigraph of $\sin x$ (restricted to $[-\pi, \pi]$) is a straight line connecting $(-\pi / 2, -1)$ and $(\pi , 0)$ on $[-\pi / 2, \pi]$ and follows $\sin$ elsewhere. So your counterexample is not a counterexample as stated, but the domain can be modified so that it is correct.

Comment: It can't be a straight line. You'll chop off a small sliver of the convex portion of the sine curve if you do that

Comment: (I'm glad we agree though that the general concept is sound)

Comment: In case you’re still not convinced, please answer my initial question: how do I express $(\pi, -1)$ as the convex combination of points in the epigraph of $\sin x$ on $[-\pi ,\pi]$? I don’t think you can. The only way to do so is if you extend the domain of $\sin$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes, actually, you’re right. It’s not straight.

Comment: Oh I agree that $(pi,-1)$ is not a valid point.

Comment: Theoretical Economist and Michael Grant, thanks for the discussion. The point raised by Michael Grant is clearer to me now, and I updated the answer accordingly (I'd rather not delete this answer as I think it is valid as a partial answer or at least, as an extended comment to OP's question).

Comment: I interpret this result as saying the finding the convex hull of an epigraph is at least as hard as nonlinear optimization.

Comment: @Rahul, well, I still believe the P1 and P2 are not equivalent so Prof. Ali Ahmadi is incorrect in claiming so. For two problems to be equivalent, any solution to one must quickly lead to a solution to the other, and vice versa. Yes, a solution to P1 does lead to a solution to P2, but it is _not_ the case that all solutions to P2 lead to solutions to P1. They simply are not equivalent. But you are right, it is _also_ true that finding that convex hull in P2 is not necessarily tractable, further reducing the _practical_ value of such a transformation. TANSTAAFL.

Comment: @shamisen I support leaving this answer here too! thanks for the edit.